# Marcar/Desmarcar todos checkbox exceto os desabilitados

Tags: javascript

Nesse script abaixo ele marca e desmarca todos os *checkbox* mas gostaria que quando um checkbox estiver "checked" e "disabled" não altere nada. O problema é que não sei como fazer isso, alguém teria uma ideia?

```
<input type="checkbox"                  class='marcar'  />
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled class='marcar'  />
```

JS:

```
<button class='btn btn-large' type='button' title='Todos' id='todos' onclick='marcardesmarcar();'>
       <i class='icon-large  icon-ok'>Click</i>
</button>

<script>
function marcardesmarcar() {
    $('.marcar').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) 
           $(this).attr("checked", false);
        else 
           $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `$(this).prop('disabled')` para verificar o estado dessa propriedade. E juntar no teu if assim:

```
    if (this.checked) {
        if ($(this).prop('disabled')) return;
        else this.checked = false;;
    }
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzeobpf2/