# Botão de marcar e desmarcar todos checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Primeiramente, existe essa pergunta sobre [Marcar/Desmarcar todos checkbox exceto os desabilitados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119716/marcar-desmarcar-todos-checkbox-exceto-os-desabilitados), no entanto não quero que desmarque o que já estão marcado quando clicar novamente. Quero que ao clicar no botão, desmarque todos os *checkboxes*, mas caso tenha alguma marcado, ele deve permanecer marcado.

A ideia é verificar se a maioria dos *checkboxes* estão marcados, então desmarca-los. Caso contrário, marca-los.

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, vejam:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#checkAll", function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",  true);      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>Jon Snow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>Tony Stark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>Paul McCartney</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>Luke Skywalker</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>Pablo Escobar</td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <button style="float: left;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="checkAll">Botão</button>
```

Gostaria que ao clicar novamente, desmarcasse os *checkboxs*. Qual seria melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Ficou confusa sua pergunta. Caso tenha 2 marcados e clique no botão, o que deveria acontecer?

Comment: @DavidSamm se tiver dois 2 marcados e não clicou nenhuma vez em marcar tudo, ele deve marcar o restante que estão desmarcados.

Comment: Vc quer verificar se o botão "marcar tudo" já foi clicado antes?

Comment: Se entendi, vc só quer saber se pelo menos a metade dos boxes estão marcados. Caso sim, desmarcar tudo, do contrário marcar os que estão vazios.

Comment: @DavidSamm se caso isso for uma saída, pode ser. O que eu não quero é que seja igual a resposta da pergunta que eu citei https://jsfiddle.net/wzeobpf2/. Porque lá  no momento em clico em marcar tudo [exemplo], ele desmarca os que já estão marcados. [Que difícil explicar =/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pergunta não ficou muito clara então consegui fazer isso, verifique se te responde e caso contrario poste no comentário para que eu possa te ajudar.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#checkAll').click(function(){
    let desmarcados = $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length;
    let marcados = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    console.log(marcados);
    console.log(desmarcados);
    if(marcados > desmarcados){
       $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
    }else{
      $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/>Jon Snow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/>Tony Stark</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/>Paul McCartney</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/>Luke Skywalker</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

     <button style="float: left;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="checkAll">Marcar tudo</button>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo... só não estava conseguindo expressar direito. Vlw.

Comment: O código acima não funciona como explicado quando a metade dos boxes estão marcados. Teria que alterar a linha `marcados > desmarcados` para `marcados >= desmarcados`.

Comment: @DavidSamm não entendi direito seu comentário, poderia me explicar melhor para que eu possa melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Os "marcados" devem que ser MAIOR OU IGUAL que a metade (`>=`) do número de boxes, e não MAIOR (`>`).

Comment: O autor : 'A ideia é verificar se a maioria dos checkboxes estão marcados' , logo pensei que era >